# In Matthew 21:16, did Jesus misquote Psalms 8:2 by saying “praise” instead of “strength”?

Tags: matthew, jesus, psalms

The English translation of Matt. 21:16 according to the King James Version states,

> <sup>16</sup> And said unto him, Hearest thou what these say? And Jesus saith unto them, Yea; have ye never read, Out of the mouth of babes and sucklings thou hast perfected **praise**? <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

However, the English translation of Psa. 8:2 according to the King James Version states,

> <sup>2</sup> Out of the mouth of babes and sucklings hast thou ordained **strength** because of thine enemies, that thou mightest still the enemy and the avenger. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

Did Jesus misquote Psa. 8:2 in Matt. 21:16 by saying the word “praise” instead of the word “strength” as found in the psalm?